# What is the meaning of "multiply by" in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

This is the context:

> Two sheets of paper from a phonebook may slide
>   across each other quite easily, but **multiply** that friction **by** the number of pages in two
>   phonebooks by interweaving the pages and you've got yourself a monster
>   capable of lifting an entire car.
>
> Source: [Vsauce: Is 5-second rule true?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SiAm9OZNy-s) from 07:19 to 07:34

What is the meaning of "multiply by" in this context? Does it mean "increase" or just means "performing multiplication"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is just mathematical multiplication.

If friction on each sheet = F and number of sheets = n, then total friction= F×n